# Django form view to create and update object model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model called `RecordsCategory` which has only field called `name` on two below addresses

1. `record_category/create/`
2. `record_category/update/`

how can I write my *FormView* for both updating and creating?

**models.py**

```py
class RecordsCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
class RecordCategoryView(FormView):
    ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use django generic UpdateView and CreateView.

views.py

```
class RecordCategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = RecordsCategory
    fields = ['field name']
```

repeat the same with UpdateView making sure you make the right changes along the way.

Comment: Is there way to save data to DB while using the FormView

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help you with that sorry. However, unless you really need to make a custom FormView for your model, especially at the beginning I would suggest sticking to what is provided by Django for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Let's consider a scenario where we *create* a `RecordsCategory` and *update/edit* the `RecordsCategory` using Django forms.

Suppose you have a certain model as follows:

```py
class RecordsCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Now, let's add forms:

```py
class RecordsCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RecordsCategory
        fields = '__all__'


    def save(self):
        record_category = super(RecordsCategoryForm, self).save(commit=False)
        record_category.save()
        return record_category
```

If you observe the save method, we are first trying to get the record category object without saving it to the database (via `commit=False`). This is to make sure that the application doesn't raise `IntegrityError`(which means we are trying to save to DB without entering/filling mandatory fields). Then we are saving it to the database.

Let's add views for `create new record category`:

```py
from django.views.generic import FormView

class NewRecordsCategoryView(FormView):
    template_name = "blob/blob.html"
    form_class = RecordsCategoryForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(NewRecordCategoryView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("some url name")
```

We have overridden `form_valid` method of `NewRecordsCategoryView` to `save()` method that we have overridden above. Specially since we can't access request objects in models/forms, we need to pass to `save()` method.(we can also pass to `__init__` method of form, that's another way).

Now, let's add another view to update the record category object:

```py
class EditRecordsCategoryView(UpdateView) #Note that we are using UpdateView and not FormView
    model = RecordsCategory
    form_class = RecordsCategoryForm
    template_name = "blob/blob.html"

    def form_valid(self, form): # here you should be redirected to the id which you want to change it.
        form.save()
        return super(EditRecordsCategoryView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("some url name")
```

And with these urls:

```
    ...
    path('record_category/create/', NewUserProfileView.as_view(), name="new-user-profile"),
    path('record_category/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/', EditUserProfileView.as_view(), name="edit-user-profile"),
    ...
```

And the basic Django template to make the above forms work:

```html
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type=submit value="submit" />
</form>
```

References:

- [**Adding and editing model objects using Django class based views and forms**](https://django.cowhite.com/blog/adding-and-editing-model-objects-using-django-class-based-views-and-forms/)
- [**How to reference the newly created object using FormView** <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27595910/11833435)
- [**`django.views.generic.edit.FormView`** <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview)
- [**`Django ModelForm: What is save(commit=False) used for?`** <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848678/11833435)